# Netbeans - Can a Java Application React to 'Stop'?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've googled for quite some time now but I couldn't find any threads about if an application, started with Netbeans as 'Run' or 'Debug', is able to recognize if you 'Stop' it with Netbeans (clicking on the big red square at 'Outputs' or in the 'Debug' toolbar) and still is able to do some work, i.e. write a config before terminating.

I guess it can't because it probably just kills the JRE thread, but maybe I'm wrong and there is a chance to let the application do some work even if it gets shut down like this.

Comment: I guess, you won't use your program within NB in production, want you ? To shutdown a Java program from outside, a common pattern is to listen on a network socket and do a clean shutdown on request. Or using [addShutdownHook()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

Comment: No, not in production. Though our company develops with Netbeans and the developers test/debug with it and the support tests with it as a normal Program like the customers get it. Mainframe and internal windows positions/sizes, tablecolum ordering, positioning, filtering, split positions etc. are written like every 5 minutes and on shutdown into the database for each user profile and some programmers asked if there was no way writing those when the debug gets stopped via Netbeans so they don't have to set their views up again. But as Tom K wrote and I thought, the JVM just gets killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stop kills the JVM. The JVM has no way to detect if it is killed thus there is no way to do something after that.